# JQuery highlight menu item with an image when user selects it and change background color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JQuery/Javascript newbie here. I've created a menu. When a user hovers over an item in the menu I want the background color to change. (Easy to do with CSS.) When a user actually selects an item, I want an arrow to appear on top of the item name (like a hover effect with background image) BUT, unlike the hover effect, I want the arrow to stay until the user selects another item on the menu. Basically, I'm trying to recreate what Zappos has done here (**see mini floating menu to the left of the shoes**): http://www.zappos.com/dr-scholls-jamie-black-dot?zfcTest=fcl%3A0.

I looked at many Stackoverflow questions and answers about highlighting a selected menu item but, none were quite what I'm looking for which is exactly what the Zappos floating menu does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

anaanzi

Comment: they did it with a css class, (inspect to see for urself) `on`.

Comment: Right! Thanks for responding! I viewed the source code and saw the CSS. Are they doing it with nested classes or something?. I'm actually looking for some explicit help on how to code this please- whether it's just CSS or CSS and JavaScript/JQUERY. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what I did [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/Z8W5N/).

To do the similar effect at zappos

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul li').hover(
        function() {
        if ( !$('div').hasClass('blue') ) {
            $(this).addClass('gray');
        }
        },
       function() {
           $(this).removeClass('gray');
       }
    );

    $('ul li').click( function() {
        $('ul li').removeClass('blue');
        $(this).addClass('blue');
    });
});
```

Edit: You can add the arrow effect that you want by adding an background with the arrow to the css class. Depending if you want the arrow on hover (gray class) or on click (blue class)

Comment: Hi Ricardo. This is great, thank you!! Is there a reason you're performing the JQuery function on the li tag instead of a tag? That's how I have it set up now- with the a tag. Although from my research I think this may cause a problem with the JQuery code because the urls have a # in them (because they're pointing to divs with matching ids.) How would I swap the blue square for an arrow (image) appear (Like Zappos)?

Comment: I was looking at the wrong box. My FF showed me the picture gallery floating in the left. I checked using private browsing and it was showing the box that you want with the arrow. The code is almost the same. Only the css changes. Check this [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/Z8W5N/).

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thanks so much Ricardo!! Just a few questions...I want to make sure I understand the code. Why are you performing the JQuery function on the li tag instead of a tag? What do the ids for the li tags do? (I didn't find a reference for them in the JQuery or CSS.) Thanks again!!

Comment: The ID on the li is to identify what li has been clicked, so that we can add the arrow when people click on it. You also switch the content based on that id. You could try with the a too, but you don't need it. Switch the content based on the li id, if you want, get the a href with jquery and perform an action.. You can go from what I wrote and do many things.

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thanks again for your help. The JQuery code works great! I have another question. My arrow image is a full image of an arrow (not just the arrow tip like in Zappos). I've set the li width to 200px and made the image itself wider than that (230px) so it will fill up the entire li (with padding) and pop a bit outside of the borders. If the li width's not set, the arrow image pushes the li borders out. If the li width's set, the border's not pushed out but image is cut off. I've tried making the image smaller too and its still cut off. Any help with this would be appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: just wanted to add that I have the li set to "display: block;". Thanks!

Comment: Here's my JS Fiddle so you can see what I mean: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MuL5f/2/)

Comment: This requires a different approach. I played with what you have and this is what I think it should be done. To make the fill background try li bigger 230 the size of the image. To make the hover effect on the other Li, you need to create a background without the arrow for the hover effect. You can't do it just with css.

Comment: Great thanks Ricardo! I appreciate you taking the time. I'll play around with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for the hover effect. Assuming the navigation is an unordered list with the class of "nav" the code would look something like this:

```
.nav li a:hover {
  background: #95ACC3;
}
```

As for the click effect, you'll want to use jQuery to add a class to whatever list item that is clicked. For an example, the code below first removes the class 'active' from all the list items (this ensures only one item has the class 'active' at a time), then it adds the 'active' class to whatever item was clicked.

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a working example of what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/8CMxG/

Comment: This is awesome Travis, thanks so much for taking the time! When the menu item is selected, I'd like an arrow image (like in the Zappos menu) to appear. So when a user clicks on a menu item the arrow image will appear and stay until another item is clicked. Can you please tell me how to do that?